# apache flink java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lambda deserialization when attempting to write to AvroParquet sink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have the following flink program:

```
object StreamToHive {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val builder = KafkaSource.builder[MyEvent]
    builder.setBootstrapServers("localhost:29092")
    builder.setProperty("partition.discovery.interval.ms", "10000")
    builder.setTopics("myevent")
    builder.setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest)
    builder.setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest)
    builder.setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.of(new MyEventSchema))
    val source = builder.build()

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val streamSource = env
      .fromSource[MyEvent](source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks[MyEvent](), "Kafka Source")

    val sink: StreamingFileSink[MyEvent] = StreamingFileSink
      .forBulkFormat(new Path("hdfs://localhost:50070/mydata"),
        AvroParquetWriters.forReflectRecord[MyEvent](classOf[MyEvent])
      )
      .build()
    streamSource.addSink(sink)
    env.execute()
  }
}
```

But executing this fails with `apache flink java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lambda deserialization`. I assume I have something completely wrong, but what? What must a do to be able to write POJO instances to an HDFS instance?
Reading from Kafka works all fine.

With the class MyEvent defined like this:

```
class MyEvent() extends Serializable{
  @JsonProperty("id")
  var id:String = null
  @JsonProperty("timestamp")
  var timestamp:Date = null
}
```

The namenode is running with the following docker-compose services:

```
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: namenode
    volumes:
      - ./hdfs/namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=hive
    env_file:
      - ./hive/hadoop-hive.env
    ports:
      - "50070:50070"
    networks:
      - shared

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: datanode
    volumes:
      - ./hdfs/datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./hive/hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070"
    depends_on:
      - namenode
    ports:
      - "50075:50075"
    networks:
      - shared

  hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-server
    env_file:
      - ./hive/hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
    depends_on:
      - hive-metastore
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
    networks:
      - shared

  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./hive/hadoop-hive.env
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
    depends_on:
      - hive-metastore-postgresql
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"
    networks:
      - shared

  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
    container_name: hive-metastore-postgresql
    volumes:
      - ./metastore-postgresql/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    depends_on:
      - datanode
    networks:
      - shared
```

Answer (score 1):

SJ, you may have this dependency in your maven pom's front part.

```
    <dependency>-->
         <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>-->
          <artifactId>flink-connector-hive_2.12</artifactId>-->
            <version>${flink.version}</version>-->
            <scope>compile</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

This dependency will introduce `org.apache.flink.hive.shaded.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter` inside of the real `AvroParquetWriter.class` you want to use.